# How do you wait for multiple types of events in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

When waiting for an event with discord.py you can use `commands.Bot.wait_for('message', timeout=30, check=check)` or something similar with `'reaction_add'`.

Is there a way to wait for a `message` OR `reaction`? The only way I can think of is starting another thread and running two `commands.Bot.wait_for()` at the same time, but that seems really scuffed.

If there is a method that allows you to wait for multiple types of events that'd be great to know. If anyone has any ideas please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `wait_for` multiple events using `asyncio.wait`

```py
done, pending = await asyncio.wait([
                    bot.wait_for('message'),
                    bot.wait_for('reaction_add')
                ], return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
```

`asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED` stops the wait when at leasts one task is completed and returns that as `done`. Look into the docs for more info

### References:

-[`asyncio.wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#waiting-primitives)

Comment: It looks like you can't specify which event to stop the wait so this will not work for my purposes. However, it does answer the question I asked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `commands.Bot.add_listener(function, 'on_message')` to create a listener, and when the `commands.Bot.wait_for` passes or times out, remove the listener.